# Error: Use of undeclared type 'NSImage' in Swift (Xcode 6 Beta 7)

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I am experiencing a very strange behaviour in Xcode 6 Beta 7 and Swift. I am getting the error "Use of undeclared type 'NSImage'" all over the place in the editor, but I believe everything is OK in the code: I have imported Cocoa by "import Cocoa" in all files using Cocoa, etc.

Actually, when I compile the program, the errors go away and the program runs fine! But when I go to the editor again to edit a file, the errors pop up again.

I assume this is an Xcode bug (I assume the alerts in the editor being accurate, the code wouldn't even compile). Does anybody know a solution or workaround to this issue?

P.D.: I've already tried cleaning and deleting Derived Data, with no luck.

Comment: The error doesn't say only Use of undeclared type 'NSImage'... The editor actually gives the error for any single Cocoa class!!! It's almost impossible to work like this...

Comment: I found that importing Quartz in all files using Cocoa classes solves the issue. But I shouldn't need Quartz (I am not using it anywhere!) or, if I really have to import Quartz, the code should _not_ compile without importing it. I am wrong?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, except only in my swift Cocoa Framework. Are you building a framework using swift as well?

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem with my NSManagedObject subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was building a Cocoa Framework with swift.

NSImage is part of AppKit. It seems like an NSApplication is somehow getting the AppKit framework injected by default, but not my framework Target. By linking the framework with the AppKit framework:

[image: Linking AppKit]

I now have no problems using NSImage. Hope this helps you!